# I'm trying to install scoop on my windows laptop in powershell version 7.3.1 (the latest one) but getting errors related to connection issues

Tags: powershell

I tried using the commands `irm get.scoop.sh | iex` and `iwr -useb get.scoop.sh | iex` but both of them giving the same error which is stated below.

`Invoke-RestMethod: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.`

Please help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you access the resource otherwise (like in your browser)? Try to open https://get.scoop.sh and also https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scoopinstaller/install/master/install.ps1 (to which it redirects).

Comment: No, I'm not able to access the script. It shows ```raw.githubusercontent.com took too long to respond.```

Comment: Then the issue is with your connection/content filtering/firewall/ISP blocking the traffic to  this. Can you access https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ and https://github.com/ in general? If you can access GitHub you can copy the contents from https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Install/blob/master/install.ps1 save it in a ps1 file and run it in PowerShell.

Comment: I can access ```github.com``` but not ```raw.githubusercontent.com```. Also what to do about the connection settings thing ?? Any suggestions ??

Comment: So if you can access github.com you can follow what I said about installing Scoop.

Comment: About the connection, it's impossible for me to know what blocking stuff you have between your PC, Network, ISP, Country and raw.githubusercontent.com. But maybe use a VPN or something like it. (What's the response if you do - in commend line - ```nslookup raw.githubusercontent.com```?)

Comment: ```Server:  reliance.reliance

Address:  2405:201:8008:3071::c0a8:1d01

Name:    raw.githubusercontent.com
Addresses:  2405:200:1607:2820:41::36
          49.44.79.236```

Comment: Also I tried installing scoop the way you suggested then I tried installing winfetch then it returned connection error.

Comment: Because winfetch also uses the same raw.githubusercontent.com. 49.44.79.236 IS NOT the IP address for the GitHub servers, it's some IP in India that I'd bet is used by the ISP or government to block certain stuff. You should try using a VPN software on your computer.

Comment: Actually, it seems from https://broadbandforum.co/threads/vlc-media-player-website-blocked-on-many-isps-in-india.214362/post-1570571 that it's just the ISP blocking it through DNS. You can change your computer's DNS servers to Google's/Cloudflare/Open DNS or something alike.

Comment: 2405:201:8008:3071::c0a8:1d01 Is an ip address in India also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that you do not have access to the location you're trying to download from. For Scoop, that location is https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Install/blob/master/install.ps1 (you can try accessing it in a browser, and it will fail as well.)

You can do an installation of Scoop more manually:

1. Go to https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Install/blob/master/install.ps1 and click on ***Copy raw contents***:
   [image]
2. Open notepad and paste the content you copied
3. Save the file as a ***.ps1*** file (e.g. *Install.ps1*)
4. In PowerShell open this file, and it will run the installation and install Scoop

As for the reason of the connection issue.

Based on the IP raw.githubusercontent.com is resolving to (`49.44.79.236`) it seems to be caused by the ISP (Jio) blocking it and resolving it to an incorrect IP.

You can get potentially around it by one of those options (try in order):

1. Changing your DNS provider on the computer to something else, like [Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using), [Cloudflare](https://1.1.1.1/dns/), [OpenDNS](https://www.opendns.com/setupguide/), or something like them
2. Use an encrypted connection (mainly for DNS but also for more) like Cloudflare's WARP: https://cloudflarewarp.com/
3. Install a VPN software to bypass all restrictions by ISP

Comment: Thank you, it works now :)

Comment: @AmanBahl, if my answer solved your question, you can accept it as the answer by clicking the "checkmark" button underneath the vote buttons beside the answer.